# Preform a bitwise to decode a syslog priority code

Tags: powershell, bit-manipulation, syslog

I'm trying figure how to decode a syslog priority code in powershell.  I know the priority code is a combination of the facilty and severity of the message, and that the facility is mutiplied by 8 before being added to the severity code, but I'm not sure how to code this in Powershell.

So the priority of `37/8 = 4.625`, which gives you a **4=Facility**

and the priority of `37-(4*8)=5`, which gives you a **5=Severity**

The 4 Facility is a security/authorization message

The 5 Severity is a Notice: normal

All of this is outlined in the RFC 3164 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt), but I'm not sure how I can do this decoding in Powershell code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (no bitwise):

```
function get-syslog {
param($pri)

[int]$facility = [Math]::truncate([decimal]($pri/8))
$severity = $pri - ($facility *8 )

"Facility is $facility - Severity is $severity"
}
```

use:

```
get-syslog -pri 23
Facility is 2 - Severity is 7
```

Comment: Edited to replace 'Priority' with 'Severity' ;)